# Need help finding and indexing a sequence of entries in a list Python

Tags: python, list

I am looking to find a sequence of entries within a specific list and then find it's location so that I may add some extra entries on the sequence after a specific point. I need to find this out as I'm working on a Grid-based board for a turn based game that I need to store data in at any time necessary.

My code is currently:

CreateWorld.py:

```
global BaseHealth
BaseHealth = 10

global BaseHappiness
BaseHappiness = 10

global BaseIntelligence
BaseIntelligence = 10

global BaseProduction
BaseProduction = 10

global BaseWealth
BaseWealth = 10

global Tiles
Tiles = []


#The Process of Generating a Blank Map xAxis long and zAxis wide
def createLandscape(xAxis, zAxis):
    #Sets the amount of createdRows to 0
    createdRows = 0

    #Calls createRow() the amount of times that the Map is Long
    while createdRows < xAxis:
        createRow(createdRows, zAxis)
        createdRows += 1

#The Process of Generating a Blank Map Row zAxis Wide and with a Row Number of RowsCreated
def createRow(RowsCreated, zAxis):
    #Sets the amount of createdTiles to 0
    createdTiles = 0
    createdRows = RowsCreated

    #Calls createTile() the amount of times that the Row is wide
    while createdTiles < zAxis:
        createTile(createdRows, createdTiles)
        createdTiles += 1

#The Process of Generating a Blank Map Tile in the 
def createTile(RowsCreated, TilesCreated):
    global Tiles
    Tiles.append(RowsCreated)
    Tiles.append(TilesCreated)
    Tiles.append("end")
```

Main File:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1,'/BaseGame')

from Startup import Start
from Startup import MainMenu
from BaseGame import CreateWorld

global Tiles


#Start.start()
#MainMenu.listMenu_Main00()
CreateWorld.createLandscape(3, 3)


Tiles.insert()
print Tiles
```

I want to be able to take a list of multiple entries of

[x location, z location, whatever, whatever end, x location, z location, whatever end, x location, z location, whatever, whatever, whatever end, etc]

and then add a whatever into right after where x location is for example, 32 and z is 50. So it'd end up being

(... 32, 50, whatever, end)

Comment: Do you intend for the grid size to stay fixed or are you expecting to increase the size of a row to accommodate the inserted items?

Comment: No, rows are only described by the x location, z location. Everything from that until the next x location, z location are simply features of that grid space

Comment: OK... so then the question is how to insert an item into a list and move the other elements to the right?

Answer (score 0):

It might be beneficial to use a `dict` for this sort of thing. You could for example use the global `Tiles` and its indexes to access a particular tile.

```
Tiles = [{'x_loc':32, 'z_loc':50, 'stuff1':"stuff1", 'stuff2':"stuff2"},
         {'x_loc':33, 'z_loc':51, 'stuff3':"stuff3", 'stuff4':"stuff4"},
         {'x_loc':34, 'z_loc':52, 'stuff5':"stuff5", 'stuff6':"stuff6"}
        ]
```

So for example:

```
>>> for id, item in enumerate(Tiles):print(Tiles[id]['x_loc'])
... 
32
33
34
>>> for id, item in enumerate(Tiles):print(Tiles[id]['x_loc'], item)
... 
(32, {'z_loc': 50, 'x_loc': 32, 'stuff1': 'stuff1', 'stuff2': 'stuff2'})
(33, {'z_loc': 51, 'stuff4': 'stuff4', 'x_loc': 33, 'stuff3': 'stuff3'})
(34, {'z_loc': 52, 'stuff5': 'stuff5', 'x_loc': 34, 'stuff6': 'stuff6'})
```

And then you could update the items, add to them, or copy from another tile:

```
>>> Tiles[1]
{'z_loc': 51, 'stuff4': 'stuff4', 'x_loc': 33, 'stuff3': 'stuff3'}
>>> Tiles[1].update({'stuff4':'stuff4updated'})
>>> Tiles[1]
{'z_loc': 51, 'stuff4': 'stuff4updated', 'x_loc': 33, 'stuff3': 'stuff3'}
>>> Tiles[1].update({'stuff4':'stuff4updatedtwice', 'stuff3':'stuff3updated'})
>>> Tiles[1]
{'z_loc': 51, 'stuff4': 'stuff4updatedtwice', 'stuff3': 'stuff3updated', 'x_loc': 33}
>>> Tiles[1]
{'z_loc': 51, 'stuff4': 'stuff4updatedtwice', 'stuff3': 'stuff3updated', 'x_loc': 33}
>>> Tiles[1].update({'stuff2':Tiles[0]['stuff2']})
>>> Tiles[0]
{'z_loc': 50, 'x_loc': 32, 'stuff1': 'stuff1', 'stuff2': 'stuff2'}
>>> Tiles[1]
{'z_loc': 51, 'stuff4': 'stuff4updatedtwice', 'stuff2': 'stuff2', 'stuff3': 'stuff3updated', 'x_loc': 33}
```

To find a sequence of entries will depend on what the grid dimensions are.

In my example I am using a 1x3.

So to find a series I will create a 3x3 and then use an index range.

```
>>> Tiles2 = [Tiles,Tiles,Tiles]
>>> Tiles2[0][0:2]
[{'z_loc': 50, 'x_loc': 32, 'stuff1': 'stuff1', 'stuff2': 'stuff2'}, {'z_loc': 51, 'stuff4': 'stuff4updatedtwice', 'stuff2': 'stuff2', 'stuff3': 'stuff3updated', 'x_loc': 33}]
>>> Tiles2[0:1][0:2]
[[{'z_loc': 50, 'x_loc': 32, 'stuff1': 'stuff1', 'stuff2': 'stuff2'}, {'z_loc': 51, 'stuff4': 'stuff4updatedtwice', 'stuff2': 'stuff2', 'stuff3': 'stuff3updated', 'x_loc': 33}, {'z_loc': 52, 'stuff5': 'stuff5', 'x_loc': 34, 'stuff6': 'stuff6'}]]
```

`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by automatically. The number of Tiles that can be generated will be limited to the amount of RAM that is being used on the computer. And the Tiles are not added automatically with the code that you have supplied. The code would need to rewritten to handle dictionaries. I was just trying to highlight how dictionaries can be used for inserting any type of entries. It also helps for access as it doesn't require indexing and then searching based on hard coded positions within a list. As shown by using `enumerate()` and then having to do an `item[item.index('string')]`

Comment: I just got around to learning how to use Dictionaries and in 10 minutes I had my code working! It was way easier that it at first seemed too! I would very much like to thank you for your help. Dictionaries are going to make my workload much lighter than I initially thought. I wish you fortune in your future Pythonian works.

Comment: Thats great to hear you got it working. I know I didn't answer your question directly, but looking at your code it made more sense to me to go with dictionaries.